# If $f=0$ on $\gamma$, show that $f=0$ inside $\gamma$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be analytic inside and on a simple closed curve $\gamma$. If $f=0$ on $\gamma$, show that $f=0$ inside $\gamma$.

I am not sure where to begin with this. Do I need to use Cauchy's inequality? Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Follows from the uniqueness theorem. Or Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: The hypotesis regarding the curve can be weakened to "the image of $\gamma$ is not a single point", since the uniqueness theorem can still be applied